# Compiled PHP Framework

Tags: php, orm, frameworks, kohana

**I DON'T WANT TO COMPILE PHP TO NATIVE EXES OR ANYTHING LIKE THAT, ONLY COMPILE/CACHE (both words don't reflect what I mean) THE FRAMEWORK LOGIC ITSELF**

Is there anything like a compiled PHP Framework?

What I mean is take Kohana as an example. It's extensible, overrideable, fun, etc. But it ends up loading 200 files to show one page!

What I would think is best is if you have `Controller_Admin extends Controller_Admin_Template extends Controller_Template extends Kohana_Controller_Template extends Controller extends Kohana_Controller`. This isn't needed... if we just copypasted method bodies to `$parent->whatever()` it would end up in one nice, smaller, faster file.

We already do it for JS and CSS to minimise assets downloaded; why not the whole framework? :D

Also I am looking for a compileable ORM. The Kohana ORM is very... slow... it uses magic methods, loads tables, generally is fun to work with but a pain in the... circuitry of the server. :P

If we could make `ORM::factory('test')->compiled()->where('bla','=','1)->execute();` to compile into `ORMC::factory('test','SELECT * FROM test WHERE bla=1')->execute();` in the production server it would be cool. This applies to a bunch of other stuff besides ORM but ORM would benefit greatly.

The overhead of dynamic frameworks doesn't seem to tip the scales by the ease of use in my opinion. With this we lose no ease and speed it up a lot. ;)

So my question is: Does something like this exist? If not, is my logic flawed?

---

Edit:

Because of failed answers I'll show more straight what I want to do.

We have an /application/ where there is the EXACT SAME code as without "compiling", and a /compiled_app/ where all (for example) queries that can be SIMPLIFIED are SIMPLIFIED (not object Query_Builder but `SELECT blablablabla` etc).

Also as much as having 50 files for one class adds a lot of umm... override vectors? :D it is an UNNEEDED 100% GUARANTEED <s>BOTTLENECK</s> PERFORMANCE OVERHEAD. Maybe it's not much but it's there always. And it doesn't have to.

Comment: I don't know Kohana, but most of (good) PHP frameworks such as Symfony and ZF cache their stuff. Otherwise they wouldn't be that fast. I've learned by experience and reading other people that this is the way PHP *compiles*. -- You can give HipHop a try, but it's a bit weird and doesn't work exactly like the official versions of PHP (missing and bugged functions, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Flow3](http://flow3.typo3.org/) framework and [how it works](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/aspect-oriented-programming-in-php/). Its not really what you want but maybe you will find it interesting..

Answer (score 1):

PHP is an interpreted language and doesn't compile as such.

There is APC which dynamically compiles PHP code into the bytecode that the Zend engine executes and caches it.  This can gain you quite a bit of performance but it has drawbacks and limitations.

Honestly though, what you're asking for sounds an awful lot like premature optimization.  The biggest factor in deciding how fast your code will run is choice of algorithm.  A compiled bubble sort on a million records is still going to be slower than an uncompiled quicksort on the same number of records.  PHP apps also tend to spend a lot of time communicating with external systems such as databases.  You can't optimize this kind activity at all by compiling the PHP.  A query that takes 10 seconds is going to take 10 seconds whether the PHP is compiled or not.

If you are having performance issues with your application then the SQL queries it's executing is usually a good place to start when it comes to optimizing.  A lot of PHP code does too much querying, executes queries in loops, or queries for data that the application subsequently does nothing with.  Finding and eliminating these will speed your application up no end.

However, it's important to note that you should never try to optimize your code by guessing at where the bottlenecks are.  Use a tool like XDebug to generate a profile of your running code and then analyse he output to determine where the hot spots in your code are.

Most importantly, if you're not having performance problems then **optimizing for its own sake is a waste of time**.  Premature optimization wastes developer time, it tends to make source code less readable and harder to maintain, and it has a tendency to introduce bugs.  Only optimize when there is a proven need for it.

Comment: You obviously didn't understand the reply

Answer (score -1):

You can check [Yaf](http://php.net/yaf). It's a framework compiled to PHP extension.
Have You ever heard about [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php)? It can compile whole PHP application into one binary file.

Comment: I ment compiling the framework from PHP to PHP, compiling dynamic stuff like query builder to one string not bunch of useless methods executed 10000000 times daily the same way. I know HipHop and other stuff..